# UPDATE column with previous value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-13

Imagine a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (myid integer, myval double precision);
```

I want to update `myval` to the previous non-zero value, ordered by `myid`, if myval is equal to 0.

For that to work properly, the query has to start updating from the lowest `myid` and end with the highest one.

I really don't know from where to start this time. The following says that `window functions are not allowed in UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myval = LAG(myval) OVER (ORDER BY myid)
WHERE myval = 0
RETURNING *;
```

And more complex alternatives with FROM subqueries have ended in syntax errors or dumb outputs because the subquery is evaluated once instead of once per row. This last phrase makes me think about the `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN LATERAL ...` structure, but I haven't been able to make it work with the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update mytable t set myval=(select s.myval from mytable s where s.myid < t.myid and s.myval!=0 order by s.myid desc limit 1) where t.myid in (select myid from mytable where myval=0 order by myid for update) ;
```

results

```
select * from mytable;
 myid | myval
------+-------
    1 |     1
    2 | 0.123
    3 |     0
    4 |     5
    7 |     0

update mytable t set myval=(select s.myval from mytable s where s.myid < t.myid and s.myval!=0 order by s.myid desc limit 1) where t.myid in (select myid from mytable where myval=0 order by myid for update) ;

select * from mytable order by myid;
 myid | myval
------+-------
    1 |     1
    2 | 0.123
    3 | 0.123
    4 |     5
    7 |     5
```

Comment: It works! Do you think it could be generalized to n `myval`s? The last `WHERE` clause makes it a little bit difficult for me to think about a generalized solution for n columns.

Comment: it would be work for n values `select myid from mytable where myval in (0,1,2,3,n) order by myid for update`

Comment: No, sorry. I mean for `my_col_a`, `my_col_b`, etc...

Comment: Seems that something like this does it: `UPDATE mytable AS u SET  my_var_a = (   SELECT s.my_var_a   FROM mytable AS s   WHERE s.myid <= u.myid AND s.my_var_a != 0   ORDER BY s.myid DESC   LIMIT 1 ), my_var_b = (   SELECT s.my_var_b   FROM mytable AS s   WHERE s.myid <= u.myid AND s.my_var_b != 0   ORDER BY s.myid DESC   LIMIT 1 ) WHERE u.myid IN (   SELECT "myid"   FROM mytable   WHERE my_var_a = 0 OR my_var_b = 0   ORDER BY "timestamp" ASC FOR UPDATE )`; (Sorry, comments don't allow code format)

Answer (score 2):

**First part of the solution** : as you can't call a window function inside the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`, you can use a `cte` instead :

```
WITH list AS
(
  SELECT myval, LAG(myval) OVER (ORDER BY myid) AS new_val
    FROM mytable
   WHERE myval = 0
)
UPDATE mytable AS t
SET myval = l.new_val
FROM list AS l
WHERE t.myval = l.myval ;
```

**Second part of the solution** : for replacing the zero values with their non-zero previous value in the specified order, we can't add the clause `FILTER (WHERE myval <> 0)` to the `lag()` function because this clause is specific to the aggregate functions only (all the aggregate functions can be used as a window function by adding the `OVER()` clause behind, but the "pure" window functions are not aggregate functions). So here we can define our own aggregate function `replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value()` as follow :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value(x double precision, y double precision)
RETURNS double precision LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN y = 0
         THEN COALESCE(x, y)
         ELSE y
       END ;
$$ ;

DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value(double precision) ;
CREATE AGGREGATE replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value(double precision)
( sfunc = replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value
, stype = double precision
) ;
```

Then, for the following query :

```
SELECT myval, replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value(myval) OVER (ORDER BY myid RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  FROM unnest(array[5, 0, 0 , 0 , 6] :: double precision[]) with ordinality as a(myval, myid)
```

we get he following result :

```
myval | replaced_by_first_previous_non_zero_value
5     | 5
0     | 5
0     | 5
0     | 5
6     | 6
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is not that easy. With your example, a fragment of `myval` col ordered ASC by miyid like this one `[5, 0, 0 , 0 , 6]` would look `[5, 5, 0 , 0 , 6]` instead of `[5, 5, 5, 5, 6]`. Maybe isn't explained clear enough in the question.

Comment: @hector, your question was clear enough but I missed that important point. I've updated the answer accordingly adding the `FILTER (WHERE myval <>0)` clause. Tell me if it better fit your expectation.

Comment: I've tried to implement it but: `error: FILTER is not implemented for non-aggregate window functions`

Comment: Yes indeed I didn't test the code as proposed. As the lag() function is a window function but not an aggregate function, I propose to create our own aggregate function, see the updated answer which is tested for this time.

Comment: Could be @arutar answer simpler? What do you think?